# Can I develop for MonoTouch using VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, xamarin.ios

Is there any way to develop for MonoTouch using VB.NET, rather than C#?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this yet? if so, please do share.

Answer (score 3):

Currently Visual Basic is not supported in MonoTouch, but we plan on adding this to the mix in the future, as well as expanding our language support.

The reason for our lack of support is that in addition to shipping the VB compiler, we have to ship templates and we have to port the VB runtime which currently has many dependencies on desktop features of .NET and Mono.

Comment: Does MonoTouch support VB.NET yet? I heard somewhere that mono has a VB compiler but I don't know how or if this relates to MonoTouch, I just want to be able to write iOS or iPhone apps using VB.NET and I am dreaming of a day when this is possible.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, C# is the only supported language in Monotouch. Also, Monotouch apps are not your average managed .net assemblies. Monotouch C# code is compiled to native code (similar to Vala)

I don't expect to see VB.Net in Monotouch in the near future - as of now, Miguel and his gang is busy with Monodroid & the Mono framework proper. According to their roadmap, they do have plans to support VB.net in the future. No time-frame has been mentioned.

Comment: Although you are correct that we compile to native code, the way we get to native code is not the same that Vala does.   Vala is closer to a regular compiler, it just happens to output C as its intermediate language.  In all of our cases, we generate CIL bytecode (C#, F#, VB, etc) and then our Mono engine compiles the code to native code.   There is really no difference between VB and C# as a language.   The problem is the other bits of infrastructure that are needed to enable a language.

Comment: Does MonoTouch support VB.NET yet? I heard somewhere that mono has a VB compiler but I don't know how or if this relates to MonoTouch, I just want to be able to write iOS or iPhone apps using VB.NET and I am dreaming of a day when this is possible... is it yet?